# C++ read up to a character or another character

Tags: c++, file-io

I am wondering if it is possible to use

```
istream& get (char* s, streamsize n, char delim)
```

to read up to, for example, either + *or* -. I was thinking something like the equivalent of cin.get(char[],'+'||'-'), or if there is some clever other way to do this.

Comment: Have you tried writing the code and running it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard utility for this, as [std::getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) works with a single delimiter.

But, you could read the entire input into a string (using `std::getline` for example) and then parse it using `std::string::find_first_of`, which accepts multiple delimiters:

> Searches the string for the first character that matches any of the characters specified in its arguments.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use this code:

```
for (i=0;i <20;i++)
if(!(cin.peek == 43))
 {
    get (variable);
  }
```

What this does is that it peeks for next character using cin.peek (), this returns ascii value of the next character.

and if next character is not equal to delim then go ahead and read the next character